# A sum over all permutations

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups

I want to consider the sum 
$$\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\frac{x^{s(\sigma)}}{|\sigma|}$$
where $x$ is a real number, $s(\sigma)$ is the number of cycles of $\sigma$ and $|\sigma|$ is the product of lengths for cycles of $\sigma$. Will it possible to have an exact formula or a generating series for this number when $n$ ranges?

Comment: Have you calculated the function for small values of $n$ ? ... can you tell us what the function is for $n=2$ & $n=3$ ... maybe include these in your question ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I have calculated some values: n=1, it's x; n=2, it's $x^2+ \frac{1}{2}x$; n=3, it's $x^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{2}{3}x$; n=4, $x^4+3x^3+\frac{41}{12}x^2+\frac{3}{2}x$

Comment: @MattSamuel ... I am still thinking about it ... but you are probably right !

Comment: For $s$, do you include cycles of size $1$?

Comment: E.g. for $n = 5$ does the identity permutation $\sigma$ have $s(\sigma) = 0$ or $s(\sigma) = 5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  exponential formula  tells us  that the  OGF of  the  cycle index
$Z(S_n)$ of the symmetric group is given by

$$Z(S_n) = [w^n] 
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} a_l \frac{w^l}{l}\right).$$

In the present case we are evaluating at $a_l = x/l$ so we obtain
for $P_n(x)$ the polynomial in question

$$P_n(x) =  n! [w^n] 
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} x \frac{w^l}{l^2}\right)
= n! [w^n] \exp(x\mathrm{Li}_2(w)).$$

This is an EGF for $P_n(x).$

For computational purposes we may  use the recurrence by Lovasz of the
cycle index  $Z(S_n)$ which  yields (complexity is  partition function
rather than factorial)

$$Z(S_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n  a_l Z(S_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

We get for $P_n(x)$ that

$$P_n(x) =
(n-1)! \sum_{l=1}^n \frac{x}{l} \frac{P_{n-l}(x)}{(n-l)!}
\quad\text{where}\quad
P_0(x) = 1.$$

This yields e.g.

$$P_5(x) = {x}^{5}+5\,{x}^{4}+{\frac {125\,{x}^{3}}{12}}
+{\frac {65\,{x}^{2}}{6}}+{\frac {24\,x}{5}}$$

and

$$P_6(x) = {x}^{6}+15/2\,{x}^{5}+{\frac {295\,{x}^{4}}{12}}
+{\frac {355\,{x}^{3}}{8}}+{\frac {8009\,{x}^{2}}{180}}+20\,x.$$

We also have that the coefficients of $P_n(x)$ are given by

$$[x^k] P_n(x) = 
\frac{n!}{k!} [w^n] 
\left(\sum_{l=1}^n \frac{w^l}{l^2}\right)^k.$$

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to simplify things even further by using $Q_n(x) = P_n(x)/n!$ and $\displaystyle Q_n(x) =
\frac{x}{n}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{Q_l(x)}{n-l} $?